# Javascript - getting the exact value of a textarea

Tags: javascript

I need to get the exact value of a textarea field. There are many topics, but none of them meet my needs.
Javascript transforms the html characters.

```js
console.log(document.getElementById('t1').value);
// display: a'b => OK
console.log(document.getElementById('t2').value);
// display: a'b => KO I need to get a&#039;b
```

```html
<textarea id="t1">a'b</textarea>
<textarea id="t2">a&#039;b</textarea>
```

I must imperatively recover the exact content of the textarea (and not re-encode the content).

Do you have a solution for this issue?

Comment: JavaScript is not transforming it.

Comment: Try [innerText](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_node_innertext.asp)?

Comment: i believe it's `console.log()` which shows you "transformed" value. But the actual value is not changed.

Comment: _“Javascript transforms the html characters.”_ - no, the browser did, when it interpreted the HTML. The info you are looking for _using_ JavaScript, is not even available any more at that time. Do a `console.log(document.body.innerHTML)` instead, and you’ll see that even in there, the content is exactly the same in both places already. I guess if you really needed this original value, then you need to “intercept” it, before the browser even interprets the code as HTML. (So maybe via an AJAX request that gets the HTML source code.)

Comment: try this fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/Daniel_Hug/qPUEX/

Comment: @SaadMehmood that's not what I'm asking for, I want to retrieve the contents of the textarea code, not the user input. In your code I add a html char in the textarea, and it is interpreted https://jsfiddle.net/htv9j7L6/

Answer (score 1):

Not JavaScript is transforming anything when reading the textarea's value, but your browser is rendering the entities as their corresponding characters. So, once the page is rendered, there's no entity inside the textarea anymore, it's just the text as the end user would see it. Therefore, neither `.value` nor `.innerHTML` will be able to retrieve the entity.

If what you're trying to achieve is displaying entities inside a textarea, you'll have to double-encode them as `a&amp;#039;b` for example, by using the entity `&amp;` for the ampersand.

Comment: Yes, I think it would work javascript side, but the textarea will show &#039; and not '

Comment: I understood your problem, but as I said, there's no way for JS to read out the entities, because there no longer are any entities when the browser renders the textarea.

Comment: Ok, I understood. The solution would be to code my own textarea in a div. Thank you for your answers.